# Symfony3 Import an existing database

Tags: database, macos, web, symfony

I'm a beginner with Symfony project and I have a database called Subject1.sql I have to import this one to my new Symfony project but I don't really understand how it work, I tried the documentation's method but it doesn't work.

Maybe I did it wrong... I can assure you that the database work perfectly with php method. There's 1 CREATE_TABLE where we insert hundred of users.

Here my parameters.yml :

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: subjec1
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

I didn't touch it except for the database_name, I recently install mysql from `home brew` so I don't think that I have any user name or password for my database.

Someone can help me to import my database in my Symfony project ?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your data thought MySQL console, using source path/to/Source1.sql

Else, you can insert it with phpmyadmin. (note that it isn't recommanded)

After that, symfony2 should be able to access to the database. But really, you should consider put more details than "doesn't work" and also, get some time to follow Symfony tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, I follow the tutorial here : http://knpuniversity.com/tracks/symfony and I didn't find how to import my file.

Comment: As I said above, this isn't recommanded to use an existing database. Else, simply import your db into MySQL? Then create your entities according to your sql schema

Comment: Ok I'll do that, this is my university who gave me that sql file and said that I have to use it.